# Mysql calculate session from minute rows

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a device that (when its on) logs a rows every minute. The data looks like below;

```
datetime
2014-12-28 07:26:29
2014-12-28 07:25:29
2014-12-28 07:24:29
2014-12-28 07:23:30
2014-12-28 07:22:29
2014-12-28 02:25:33
2014-12-28 02:00:40
2014-12-28 01:49:12
2014-12-28 00:19:49
2014-12-27 23:22:39
2014-12-27 23:21:39
2014-12-27 23:20:39
2014-12-27 23:00:36
2014-12-27 22:24:52 *Start
2014-12-27 22:23:52
2014-12-27 22:22:52
2014-12-27 22:21:52
2014-12-27 22:20:52 * end
2014-12-27 21:46:28
2014-12-27 21:14:01
2014-12-27 20:00:06
2014-12-27 18:51:50
2014-12-27 18:50:50
```

I need a query that would return me the data like;

Start datetime, End Datetime, Duration

The duration is always in whole minutes.. so actually a count of the records would equal the number of the duration. So in the example above my output would have to be;

Start datetime,       End Datetime,          Duration
 2014-12-27 22:24:52  2014-12-27 22:20:52    5

A skip of more than 5 minutes would indicate a new session.

Anyone has any ideas how to do this in mysql?

Comment: That is only 4 minutes, not 5

Comment: Yes sorry.. correct.. but since the device is not very precise with logging it wouldn't matter if we would count it as 5..